Filtrar un arreglo según los elementos de otro arreglo javascript
Necesito filtrar un arreglo en base a otro y generar con ello un nuevo arreglo. Para entendernos mejor espero, es algo así:
posicionesSeleccionadas = [base,pivot];

jugadores.posicion = [base,escolta,alero,ala,pivot]

Los comparo con la instrucción:
jugadoresFiltrados = jugadores.filter(jugador => (jugador.posicion).includes(posicionesSeleccionadas));

Y me dice en ese caso que no hay ningún jugador con esas posiciones (jugadoresFiltrados se queda vacío), cuando sí la hay como es evidente. Lo intenté de varias formas y no hay manera siempre pasa lo mismo y ya no sé cómo hacerlo.
Si me dí cuenta que eso filtra los cuando las posiciones son las mismas que las del jugador, pero yo quiero que lo haga si entre las del jugador se incluyen las de la lista de las seleccionadas. Es decir, en el caso de arriba, cualquier jugador que tenga entre sus posiciones base y pivot debería salir.
Si se necesita alguna aclaración solo preguntad.
Gracias.

Actualización:
A raíz de las respuestas me he dado cuenta que había cometido un error en la pregunta (disculpas por ello). La edito más abajo:
jugadores es un arreglo de objetos cada uno de ellos sería un jugador. Entonces al recorrer jugadores, obtengo en jugador.posicion los datos que me refería antes:

Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: "16", nombre: "", apellidos: "", … }
​ ...
​
posicion: "base,escolta"
​​

y entonces mi idea era hacer un filtro que el usuario pueda utilizar para seleccionar en base a la posición mencionada. Estoy aún en modo aprendizaje en código y me lío a veces.
Me di cuenta que cuando comparo tal y como lo tenía en realidad jugador.posicion era un string (no un array) y por eso creo que da un error. Pero eso lo solucioné a través de la función split(',').
Dicho esto, las soluciones propuestas funcionan, pero no me dan el objeto jugador que en realidad necesito sino las posiciones que coinciden sin más, como bien indica la última respuesta.
En fin, no sé si ahora queda más claro.
Gracias.

Tal vez algo como jugadores.filter(jugador => jugador.posicion.some(pos => posicionesSeleccionadas.includes(pos)))

Sale algo parecido a lo que indico en mi respuesta: jugador.posicion.some sale que no está definida.

Esto ocurre porque estás utilizando los parámetros al revés. Estás intentando hacer el includes() a un tipo cadena (jugador, algo que es válido), buscando el contenido del array (posicionesSeleccionadas). Por eso siempre te va a devolver un array vacío. Dentro de la cadena, no se puede encontrar el array.
En su lugar, debes filtrar el array (posicionesSeleccionadas) usando includes() y buscar la cadena o el elemento (jugador).


/* preparacion */
const base = "BASE";
const pivot = "PIVOT";
const alero = "ALERO";
const ala = "ALA";
const escolta = "ESCOLTA";

const jugadores = {};

/* codigo */
const posicionesSeleccionadas = [base, pivot];
jugadores.posicion = [base,escolta,alero,ala,pivot]

// nota como no sólo he cambiado jugador y posicionesSeleccionadas de lugar
// también he quitado lo de `jugador.posicion` porque no hace falta en este ejemplo 
// (puede que si haga falta si estás trabajando con objetos en vez de cadenas)
jugadoresFiltrados = jugadores.posicion.filter(jugador => posicionesSeleccionadas.includes(jugador));

console.log(jugadoresFiltrados);




Eso funciona con cadenas de texto pero, basándome en la edición que has hecho de la pregunta, ¿funcionará con objetos? ¡También! Sólo hay que cambiar un poco el código.
La idea va a ser la misma, lo que quieres es recorrer el array de jugadores y comprobar si la posición que ocupan (que está en una cadena de posiciones separadas por coma) está dentro de las posiciones seleccionadas por el usuario.
Entonces lo que vas a hacer es un filtro de la lista de jugadores (con el método filter()) y vas a comprobar que alguna de las posiciones de la lista de posiciones está en la cadena posicion para ese jugador. No hace falta romper ese campo en un array porque, como indicaba antes, el método includes() funciona en cadenas y arrays.
Te vale con que una de las posiciones esté en la cadena, y para eso puedes usar el método some() que va a devolver verdadero si el valor está o falso si no lo está... que es precisamente lo que quieres que devuelva para que el filtro funcione.
Aquí de dejo un ejemplo:


const posicionesSeleccionadas = ["base", "alero"];

const jugadores = [
 { nombre: "Ricky Rubio", posicion: "base" },
 { nombre: "Alberto Herreros", posicion: "alero" },
 { nombre: "Pau Gasol", posicion: "ala,pivot" },
 { nombre: "Epi", posicion: "alero" },
 { nombre: "Fernando Romay", posicion: "pivot" },
 { nombre: "Sergio Lull", posicion: "base,escolta" }
];

const jugadoresFiltrados = jugadores.filter(jugador => 
  posicionesSeleccionadas.some(posicion =>
    jugador.posicion.includes(posicion)
  )
);

console.log(jugadoresFiltrados)




Puedes filtrar al revés (tendrás que asegurarte que pones lo de .posicion en la variable correcta). Pero el resultado final debería ser similar.

@Marcos gracias por el comentario. Me imaginaba que por ahí iba la cosa. Voy a editar, debería ser un cambio mínimo.

Es básicamente el mismo método que al principio, antes devolvía nombres de posiciones porque era lo único que había, ahora devuelve jugadores porque es lo que hay.

Pues todo perfecto, conseguí obtener lo que necesitaba en pantalla. Se filtran los jugadores al ir pulsando en las posiciones como procede. Gracias.

@jesus me alegro de que funcionara :)

@jesus Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos

Leyendo el código me da la impresión de que jugadores no es un array, sino un objeto
Entiendolo así, reemplazaría de esto:
jugadores.filter

a
jugadores.posicion.filter

Luego, por último, quedaría filtrar por posición y verificar que esta misma este incluida en posicionesSeleccionadas por medio del método includes
jugadoresFiltrados = jugadores.posicion.filter(posicion => posicionesSeleccionadas.includes(posicion))


Me temo que no funcionó. Sale el error de que que jugadores.posicion no está definida, y pensándolo es cierto. Lo que comentas de que sea un objeto puedo aclarar que jugadores es un objeto, y cada jugador dentro de jugadores tiene sus valores; si vamos a jugador.posicion los valores que están guardados son los que indico en la pregunta. Cada jugador de jugadores tiene unos valores distintos. Por lo que lo que está definido es jugador.posicion si recorrer todos los objetos de jugadores mediante la variable jugador.
